# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/celavie2017/public_html/register.php on line 169

Tags: php

I am writing a code for registering my users on my website. I keep getting this error. This is the code: Line 150-180.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :email');
$stmt->execute(array(':email' => $_POST['email']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



$stmt->execute(array(':email' => $_POST['email']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(!empty($row['email'])){
    $error[] = 'Email provided is already in use.';

    ?>
```

```
    //hash the password

$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 10));
    //create the activation code
    $activasion = md5(uniqid(rand(),true)); ?>
    <?
    if($this->input->post()) 
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'password' => $hash,
            'role' => $this->input->post('roles')       
        ); 
        $this->YOUR_MODEL->add_user($data); ?> <?
         function add_user($data)   

return $this->db->insert('login', $data);
```

`

Line 169= if($this->input->post())

Comment: You mean by ` that $this->input->post()` some inputs values ?

Comment: Exactly what it means. You can only use `$this` inside of a class.

Comment: Did you just copy this code from somewhere?

Comment: Why is the code littered with `?> <?`?

Comment: This code is a mess. You need to clean it up. You also have a lone function sitting in the middle of your code doing nothing and throwing a parsing error.

Comment: Obviously you copied this code..  Because if you wrote it,  you shouldnt have this error

Comment: So what if I copied it?

Answer (score 0):

"$this" is only available within an object context.

```
 <?php
//class 
class Foo 
{
    //property
    private $bar = 'gold';        

    //method
    public function getBar()
    {
        return $this->bar;
    }
}
?>
```

See [Classes and Objects - The Basics](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) for more information